# QTimer : class has no constructors

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, qtimer

I just started using Qt and learned of QTimers. Unfortunately, they seem to give an error and I have not seen this error described online yet:

error: C2514: 'QTimer' : class has no constructors.

I have my QTimer declared in the private section of dialog.h :

QTimer* timer;

And I instantiate it as such:

```
timer = new QTimer(this);
```

in dialog.cpp.

As this error does not show many results in a google search I am convinced I did something unthinkably dumb, but I have no idea what it is that I did wrong. Could someone please explain to me what it was that I did?

Comment: It's obvious you forgot to `#include <QTimer>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your .h file you should have

```
QTimer * timer;
```

and in your constructor you should have

```
timer = new QTimer();
```

and at the top of your header file you should have:

```
#include <QTimer>
```

And you shouldn't have any of your own classes named `QTimer`.

Hope that helps.